# Bypass capacitors, 2 voltages, 1 ground

Tags: capacitor

My circuit has 5v and 3.3v supplies.  They share a ground.  A component that uses the 3.3v supply says it needs a .01uF bypass capacitor across its power and ground pins.

Questions:

1. Does it have to literally be on the pins, or can the capacitor be on any wire connected directly to those pins?
2. Is there any issue with the ground being shared between the two power supplies with respect to the cap, which is only connected to the +3.3v supply?

Comment: It's recommended that the bypass capacitora should be connected as close as possible to the components' power pins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The capacitor doesn't have to be literally on the pins, but should be (as everyone has indicated) as close to the IC as possible.

As for the 3.3V vs 5V: You want to use a capacitor that has a voltage rating above that which it will routinely operate at, to handle the occasional spike. Most small through-hole ceramic capacitors will be rated at 25, 50, 100V or more, so you should have no problems using a given bypass capacitor on either your 5V or 3.3V supply. (Be aware that surface mount ceramic capacitors voltage ratings can be much lower, 6.3, 10, etc.)

For more information about bypass capacitors, there's a [good article at Seattle Robotics](http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/jun97/basics.html).

Comment: And don't forget about capacitor derating.

Answer (score 4):

Much more important than the location of the 0.1uF capacitor is the equivalent series resistance (ESR) of all decoupling capacitors as well as the equivalent series inductance (ESL).

That being said, caps such as low ESR low ESL ceramic, Alum and plastic Film caps these days have improved a lot over decades ago.  When the distance is too far you are essentially adding ESL and ESR to the capacitor and also radiating the ground loop near other circuits and thus injecting ground spikes.

The  self-resonant frequency and impedance vs F determines the amount of ripple reduction at RF and smaller parts have better characteristics. So large e-caps handle up 1~10MHz and small ceramics above that up to their self-resonant frequency (SRF).

[image]
[image]

- So, low ESR is 1st priority  (not all 0.1uF are the same)
- Close proximity is 2nd priority.
- Both are essential for ripple reduction at load without resonance.

Answer (score 2):

If the component is clocked at high frequency (or contains a high frequency oscillator or amplifier), put that capacitor as close to the pins as possible.

Otherwise the extra track between cap and IC gives two negative effects : a series inductance in the power supply line (meaning more noise on the PSU) which may give poorer performance from the chip, and a larger current loop transmitting more noise to (perhaps) interfere with other circuits.

Comment: I don't know if an oscillator somewhere between 1 and 20MHz is high frequency, but that's the component I am talking about.  I'll probably solder the cap directly to the pins, on the back of the board.  The front is kinda full :-D

Comment: Up to 20MHz you could probably get away with an inch or so, but still, closer is better

Answer (score 1):

1. You can connect the capacitor wherever you want as long as it is according to the schematic, BUT best practice is to connect it as close to the IC as possible to assure the best decoupling of high frecquency noise components.
2. No issues at all.

Comment: " wherever you want as long as it is according to the schematic"

Schematics fail to convey the actual layout necessary. And, it's best to place the capacitor as close as possible. Only in very dense/high speed designs is it critical, but it's usually a good thing in all boards.